# How to loop over items in a NavigableMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there any way to loop in `NavigableMap` in Java? I want to access all items in a `NavigableMap`.

Comment: NavigableMap with? i mean NavigableMap navigable = new ?           ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The same way you would loop any collection, with an iterator or for-each loop.

```
NavigableMap<K, V> map = ...

for(K key: map.keySet()) // iterate keys.

for(V value: map.values()) // iterate values.

for(Entry<K, V> entry: map.entrySet()) // iterate key/value entries.
```

Comment: It's worth adding that [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (of which NavigableMap is a child) guarantees that the collections methods (keySet, entrySet, values) will have the same ordering as the map. Personally, I wasted a lot of time looking for some "sortedEntrySet" method, but if you're just iterating, there's no need.

Answer (score 6):

A NavigableMap is a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You get all its keys using `keySet()`, all its values using `values()`, and all its entries using `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NavigableMap` extends `Map` it should still provide the methods `values()`, `keySet()` and `entrySet()`. Use those to iterate over the entries/values/keys as you'd do with any other map.

Answer (score 0):

Correct advance looping for Map should like this->

for(Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) // iterate key/value entries.

Answer (score 0):

One way to iterate over a `Map` in Java (including a `NavigableMap`) is to use its [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method:

```java
NavigableMap<String, Integer> map = getMap();

map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", key, value);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you only to get all of the items, I think you don't need use loop,just print these.

```
NavigableMap<String, Integer> nav = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
nav.put("key1", value1);
nav.put("key2", value2);
nav.put("key3", value3);
System.out.printf("The Whole:%s", nav);
```

Comment: Does not address the Question.