# How to sort ArrayList like other sorted list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`s.
One is of the `Double` type and contains distances. The other one is of the `String` type and contains city types.

These are the lists:

```
private ArrayList<Double> distance_list = new ArrayList<Double>();
distance.add(123.43);
distance.add(450.43);
distance.add(230.65);

private ArrayList<String> city_list = new ArrayList<String>();
city_list.add("Munich");
city_list.add("Berlin");
city_list.add("Frankfurt");

Collections.sort(distance_list); //to get the closest distance first
```

How can I sort the `city_list` in the same order to the matching distances?

Comment: I suggest you to embbed one distance and one city in a class. That class will implements comparable. Let me know if you want a complete code in answer

Comment: What is the relationship between the cities and the distances? Are they supposed to stay paired? You might want to create a class that has a 'city name' and a 'distance' property

Comment: yes that would be amazing

Comment: The distance list shows the distance from my home town. And I want to sort the distances and the citys by the distance to know which city is the closet and which is the second closet...

Comment: @MarekSchimmel it is done !

Answer (score 0):

## `NavigableMap`/`SortedMap`

Use a `Map` instead. A map pairs two items together, in a key-value relationship. Ask for the key to access its value partner.

Using a `NavigableMap` or `SortedMap` keeps, the keys in order.

```java
NavigableMap< Double , String > map = new TreeMap<>() ;
map.add( 123.43d , "Munich" ) ;
…
```

You can then loop that map. See: [*How to Loop in NavigableMap in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9749860/642706);

```java
for( Double key : map.keySet() )
{
    String city = map.get( key ) ;
    System.out.println( city + " = " + key ) ;
}
```

Here is a diagram graphic I made as an overview of the `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11. You can see `SortedMap` interface was added first, then later extended by `NavigableMap` interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a class that pairs both values and implements the Comparable interface, such as:

```
public class City implements Comparable<City> {

    private Double distance;
    private String name;

    // constructor, getters, setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City city) {
        return (double)(this.distance - city.getDistance());
    }
}
```

Then build a Treemap or some other Map type that keeps things sorted. I assume you wish to sort by distance.

```
//Create TreeMap
TreeMap<Double, String> cities = new TreeMap();

//Add cities
cities.put(123.43, "Munich");
```

The items will be sorted by the distances values!

Try it out and post your code if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps

- You create an englobing class

  - The class must implements Comparable (it is used in Collections.sort())
- Then you sort with Collections.sort()

```
class DistanceCity implements Comparable<DistanceCity>  {
    private Double distance;
    private String city;

    public DistanceCity(Double distance, String city) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DistanceCity o) {
        return distance.compareTo(o.distance);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DistanceCity{" + "distance=" + distance + ", city='" + city + "'}";
    }
}
```

```
private ArrayList<DistanceCity> liste;
liste = new ArrayList<>();
liste.add(new DistanceCity(123.43,"Munich"));
liste.add(new DistanceCity(450.43,"Berlin"));
liste.add(new DistanceCity(230.65,"Frankfurt"));

System.out.println(liste); // unordered
//[DistanceCity{distance=123.43, city='Munich'}, DistanceCity{distance=450.43, city='Berlin'}, DistanceCity{distance=230.65, city='Frankfurt'}]

Collections.sort(liste);

System.out.println(liste); // ordered
// [DistanceCity{distance=123.43, city='Munich'}, DistanceCity{distance=230.65, city='Frankfurt'}, DistanceCity{distance=450.43, city='Berlin'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### **A full implementation with Comparable and example**

```
class City implements Comparable<City>{
  public String name = null;
  public Double distance = 0.0;

  public City(String name, Double distance){
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(City o){
    return this.distance.compareTo( o.distance );
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return this.name;
  }

}


public class CitiesDemo{
  public static void main (String[] args ){
  City munich = new City("Munich", 123.43);
  City berlin = new City("Berlin", 450.43);
  City frankfurt = new City("Frankfurt", 230.65);

  java.util.List<City> cities = new java.util.ArrayList<City>();
  cities.add( munich );
  cities.add( berlin );
  cities.add( frankfurt );
  java.util.Collections.sort( cities );
  System.out.println( cities );
  }

}
```

Will return:

```
~/ (main)$ javac CitiesDemo.java 

~/ (main)$ java CitiesDemo

[Munich, Frankfurt, Berlin]

~/ (main)$
```

Or, you can test it here: https://ideone.com/fbbLv6